# React Native Expo : ulpoad Image to firabse Storage immediatley after the user Selects it

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

After struggling to upload image to the Firebase storage and save it to the user Firebase firestore, I finally succeeded in achieving that.

Here's how I did it:

```
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState("");

  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState("");
  const getPermission = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS !== "web") {
      const { status } =
        await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== "granted") {
        alert("Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!");
      }
    }
  };
  const getUserData = async () => {
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .get()
      .then((documentSnapshot) => {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          setUserData(documentSnapshot.data());
        }
      });
  };

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result.uri);
    }
  };

  const getPictureBlob = (uri) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload = function () {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
      };
      xhr.responseType = "blob";
      xhr.open("GET", image, true);
      xhr.send(null);
    });
  };

  // here I am uploading the image to firebase storage
  const uploadImageToBucket = async () => {
    let blob;
    try {
      setUploading(true);
      blob = await getPictureBlob(image);

      const ref = await storage.ref().child(uuid.v4());
      const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);
      console.log("link path");
      return await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e.message);
    } finally {
      blob.close();
      setUploading(false);
    }
  };

  const UpdateImage = async () => {
    let imgUrl = await uploadImageToBucket();
    if (imgUrl === null && userData.photoURL) {
      imgUrl = userData.photoURL;
    }
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .update({
        photoURL: imgUrl,
      })
      .then(() => console.log("user Upadted"));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getPermission();
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
  }, []);
```

My problem is that the user first select an image, secondly he should press upload button to upload it to Firebase storage, and finally click the update button in order to update the pic in firestore.
for I want the user to be able to upload the image to Firebase storage immediately after selecting it, without clicking the upload button.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it with this code:

```js
const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
const [userData, setUserData] = useState("");

const [uploading, setUploading] = useState("");
const getPermission = async () => {
  if (Platform.OS !== "web") {
    const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== "granted") {
      alert("Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!");
    }
  }
};
const getUserData = async () => {
  await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .get()
    .then((documentSnapshot) => {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        setUserData(documentSnapshot.data());
      }
    });
};

const pickImage = async () => {
  let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
    allowsEditing: true,
    aspect: [4, 3],
    quality: 1,
  });
  if (!result.cancelled) {
    UpdateImage(result.uri);
  }
};

const getPictureBlob = (uri) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      resolve(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
      reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
    };
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.open("GET", image, true);
    xhr.send(null);
  });
};

// here I am uploading the image to firebase storage
const uploadImageToBucket = async (img) => {
  let blob;
  try {
    setUploading(true);
    blob = await getPictureBlob(img);

    const ref = await storage.ref().child(uuid.v4());
    const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);
    console.log("link path");
    return await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e.message);
  } finally {
    blob.close();
    setUploading(false);
  }
};

const UpdateImage = async (img) => {
  setImage(result.uri);
  let imgUrl = await uploadImageToBucket(img);
  if (imgUrl === null && userData.photoURL) {
    imgUrl = userData.photoURL;
  }
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .update({
      photoURL: imgUrl,
    })
    .then(() => console.log("user Upadted"));
};

useEffect(() => {
  getPermission();
}, []);
useEffect(() => {
  getUserData();
}, []);
```

Comment: it did not work because the image need to be uploaded first then updated

Comment: but you are uploading the image in the `UpdateImage` call with `uploadImageToBucket`

Comment: Yuh. Sorry I have just notice that. Thanks for your help and time